# iOS app crashing when selecting at UITabItem

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, nszombie

I seem to have a very strange problem.  My app has a `UITabBar` which lets you select various view controllers.  If in a given selected tab item, another view controller is pushed onto the stack and then popped off the `UINavigationController`'s stack using either storyboard segues or `pushViewController` or `popViewController`, when you select another tab item, the app crashes.  I traced this and discovered that have a zombie object, namely the viewcontroller that was pushed and then popped.  The app is apparently trying to send a message to it.  Here is the log message.

`*** -[UserInputViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xa5f0620`

I see nowhere in my code where I am accessing the viewcontroller once it's been popped off the stack and presumably deallocated, and I don't do any special processing when the tab bar item is clicked.  In fact it crashes before

```
 - (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

is even called.  It would appear that somehow the tab bar still thinks this viewcontroller is allocated and on the stack, otherwise why would it try to send it a message?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Two questions. Are you using a stand alone tab bar, or a tab bar controller? Secondly, you say this: "popped off the UINavigationController's stack using either storyboard segues.." Are you popping a view controller using a segue?

Comment: I'm using a tab bar controller, I tried both popping the view controller using a segue and programmatically.  Either way it was crashing, but turns out that wasn't the issue.  I was accidentally assigning that view controller to be the tab bar controller's delegate (I was using a base view controller class which did that erroneously.)  When I changed that, the crash went away.  Solution is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14927677/view-controller-getting-a-message-sent-to-it-after-release-causes-a-crash?rq=1

Comment: In any case, you shouldn't pop off a view controller with a segue, unless you're using an unwind segue.

Comment: Yes, thank you, you're right.  I just wanted to try both approaches to see if one of them was causing the problem.  Turns out it had nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 1):

Found this problem.  That deallocated view controller was actually being assigned to be the `UITabBarController`'s delegate!  Oops.  Found this answer here.

[View Controller getting a message sent to it after release, causes a crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14927677/view-controller-getting-a-message-sent-to-it-after-release-causes-a-crash?rq=1)